# Log with the same account of the Facebook app

Tags: android, facebook

I have done a Login Activity using Facebook to registrate a user in my application. It works very well but i've found a problem: if I log with an account A in my application and then I log out and log again with an account B in the facebook app it doesn't change Session in my app.. How can I do instead that when I change account in facebook  app it change also in mine ?

Answer (score 0):

That cant happen because your app manages the session of the facebook id that you have logged on separately.